# Automate Website clicking

Tags: web

I would like to automate some repetitive online tasks. For example I would like to go through every page on a website and check if a certain text is found on that page.
I do know how to automate steps that I have already done. However I need to do this for thousands of pages.
Does anyone have any pointers to get me started? What tools/language would I need to use.
Thank you,
Joshua

Comment: I would recommend adding some specific examples and demonstrate that you did a little research before asking your questions as these are the metrics that determine UP and DOWN votes on questions. I up voted to counter the down vote you received earlier as I feel this question has value, make sure to update/edit this question to ensure others don't continue to knock your score. :)

Answer (score 0):

This type of Testing is known as End-to-End (e2e) Testing.

There are a number of frameworks built specifically for this purpose, in which the most popular is [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

You could run a Google search for alternatives. One that I was just introduced to and built for Javascript Stacks is called [NightmareJS](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) and ties in well with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/). I think it's pretty intuitive and allows you to write e2e test quickly with little code...kinda the opposite of a nightmare.

In my opinion, Javascript is the best language for writing e2e tests as it allows your developers to use a language they already have to know to build web applications, but this is all subjective of course. What ever is easiest and fastest for you and your team.